# How to CASCADE deletion to children without reference to the parent

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, cascade, cascading-deletes

Is it possible to apply cascading deletion of `child` rows on `parent` deletion to this MySQL schema?

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INTEGER,
    specialChildrenId INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

-- Always 1:1 related to whatever references it
-- (not necessarily referenced by parent)
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I cannot put a reference from the `child` to the `parent` as in my application a `child` can be either 1:1 related to a `parent` or 1:1 related to another completely different table.

Comment: You can add a trigger on the two (or more) parent tables to delete child row before delete.

Comment: @Anand Exactly what i was looking for! You should post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Now you're going to make me do work :) j/k added an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a trigger on the two (or more) parent tables to delete child row before delete like so:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER tr_parent_delete BEFORE DELETE ON parent
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM child WHERE id = OLD.specialChildrenId;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice you should always put the foreign key in the child table, and if its reference to another table, add another foreign key. In this case, your delete query would look like:

```
delete from child where parent_id=#{parentId}
```

But in your case, you have to use this query:

```
delete from child where id=
(select specialChildrenId from parent where id=#{parentId})
```